# Webpack not loading output files in localhost even after compiling successfully

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Below is my piece of code for webpack:

```
module.exports = env => {
return {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    },
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './',
        port: '8080',
        disableHostCheck: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                },

            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),

    ]
}
}
```

Also here is my package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
"@reactioncommerce/components": "^0.65.1",
"@reactioncommerce/components-context": "^1.2.0",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "^16.8.5",
"react-dom": "^16.8.5",
"react-scripts": "2.1.8",
"reacto-form": "0.0.2",
"styled-components": "^3.4.10"


 },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

THe problem here is that the code compiles correctly and shows no error at all , but doesn't show the line : output is served from localhost:8080
And hence I don't know wether it is actually running or not.But I guess there is some issue with output path or something.Can somebody please point me in the right direction here. Thanks in advance.

Edit :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React.js using NPM, Babel6 and Webpack</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why your output file is index.html ? it should be *.js file. Then in index.html you load js script.

Comment: I changed it to index.js as well but still nothing comes up in the output .

Comment: index.js is the source file. Output file should have diffrent name. Try to use `output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), filename: 'bundle.js' }`. Add index.html to your post

Comment: Made those changes and added index.html in post still  it compiles but doesn't run.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't run*? What command are you running?

Comment: Whether it's `npm run start` or `npm run build`, the scripts are only supposed to build the code, they are not supposed to start a server or anything. Perhaps were yoou expecting server to start, like when using [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)?

Comment: Yes.Indeed I was expecting the program to actually run on a localhost.Wondering where the wiring is wrong. How do I start a server given the current configurations?

Comment: Also I was running -  npm start , that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your input and output are the same. `entry` should be the path to your(s) entry in your source code, it's your input. `output` defines options as to where your bundled file will be saved. These are two different files! You *write* your source code, then you *build* it into your bundle.

What is recommended is to have `/src` for your source code and `/dist` for your product code. Your directory should look like:

```
/src
  /index.js
  /index.html
  ... rest of your source code
/dist
  /bundle.js <-- will be generated by webpack
```

To have this, your webpack config object must look like:

```js
{
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Also, your `index.html` must reference the bundled file, but don't worry - that is being taken care of by `html-webpack-module`! Simply don't link any script in `/src/index.html`!

Comment: Currently my webpack looks exactly the same. Also I will edit the original quetion's edit to reflect the current edit which doesn't have any script linked.

Comment: I was able to make it work by installing webpack-dev-server,All thanks to you for pointing me in the right direction and explaining very clearly what the difference is.